# $E[e^{X_1^2 t}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}$ then $M(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt[\color{red}n]{1-2t}}$

Tags: probability

I have $E[e^{X_1^2 t}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2t}}$. How do I get to $M(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt[\color{red}n]{1-2t}}$. Where did the $n$-th root come from?

*See last line of image*

---

**Proposition $\bf 2.4.38.\;$** *Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be $\color{darkorange}{\textit{independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.)}}$ standard normal raandom variables ($i.e\,\; X_i\overset{i.i.d.}\sim{\cal N}(0,1)$). Let* $$Z=X_1^2+\ldots+X_n^2.$$ Then $Z\sim \mathcal X_n^2.$ 
 
 *Proof.* We will use moment generating functions. We have $$\begin{align*}
M(t)\;&=\;\mathbb{E}\big[e^{Zt}\big] \\
&=\;\mathbb{E}\big[e^{t\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2}\big] \\
&=\;\prod_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\big[e^{tX_i^2}\big] \\
&=\;\mathbb{E}\big[e^{X_1^2t}\big]^n.\\
\end{align*}$$ Here we have used the independent property on the third line and the fact that the random variables are identically distributed on the last line. Now

$$\eqalign{\Bbb E\left[e^{X_1^2t}\right]
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left\{-\dfrac12(1-2t)x_1^2\right\}\mathrm dx_1\quad\dfrac12\gt t \\
&=\dfrac1{\sqrt{2\pi}(1-2t)^{1/2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left\{-\dfrac12u^2\right\}\mathrm du \\
&=\dfrac1{(1-2t)^{1/2}}.
}$$ Hence $$M(t)=\dfrac1{(1-2t)^{n/2}}\quad\dfrac12\gt t.$$

---

Also I know $M(t) = E[e^{Xt}]$ but is $M(t) = E[e^{X^{\color{red}{n}}t}]$ note $X^n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you did not obtain the $n-$th root:

$$\sqrt[n]{1-2t}\ne\left(1-2t\right)^{n/2}=\left(\sqrt{1-2t}\right)^{n}$$

The random variable $Z$ is a sum of independent, identically (normally) distributed variables $X_{i}$, squared.

Hence, you have that:

$$M(t)=\mathbb{E}e^{t(X_{1}^{2}+...+X_{n}^{2})}=\mathbb{E}e^{tX_{1}^{2}}\cdot...\cdot\mathbb{E}e^{tX_{n}^{2}}=\left[\mathbb{E}e^{X_{1}^{2}t}\right]^{n}.$$ From the formula:

$$\mathbb{E}[g(X)]=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}g(x)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

where $f$ is the pdf of $X$, you obtained:

$$\mathbb{E}e^{X_{1}^{2}t}=\frac{1}{(1-2t)^{1/2}}$$

Hence:

$$M(t)=\left(\frac{1}{(1-2t)^{1/2}}\right)^{n}=\frac{1}{(1-2t)^{n/2}}$$